# How to match a simple column and lookup column in ssrs

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting

I am using reportbuilder with sharepoint list, in which I want to  ***match a simple column and lookup column in ssrs***.

I tried this but it does not work:

```
Lookup(Fields!ID.Value,Fields!TaskMasterID1.Value,Fields!ActivityName.Value, "SSTaskActivityList")
```

What is the problem with my code and how should I fix it?

Comment: whats the error its showing?

Comment: Do you have an equal sign preceding the expression? It should work if it finds a match. Perhaps the datatypes of the IDs are different? Try: `= Lookup(Fields!ID.Value.ToString,Fields!TaskMasterID1.Value.ToString,Fields!ActivityName.Value, "SSTaskActivityList")`

Comment: yes i am having = sign preceding the expression, but not working